# Performance issues when performing DB connection check

Tags: database

I have build a little library for DB interfacing, but I am concerned about the issues which may arise if I use it in a larger scale application with heavy traffic. My implementation now is:

```
SELECT 1+1;
```

To check for connection with the DB. I have this function everywhere before making any call to the DB.

> Will this impact the performance of the application in general?
>   Can it lead to crashing the DB server?

EDIT:
Please review the pseudo code:

```
Create database object with (engine, host, dbname, user, passowrd)
send 'SELECT article FROM dbtable WHERE id=some_id' to the database
// Behind the scenes
==== if no connection, connect.
====== connect ot database, error if not able
==== else send query
// End behind the scenes
....
// Other code
```

What benefit I see in this:

1. If the connection is not needed, it is not instantiated. Lowers the number of unused connections to the server
2. Reconnect if needed
3. Can silently fallback
4. If connection dies between requests, reconnect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use this query unnecessarily. After all, what is the point doing this.

Try to execute the actual query that you want to execute. In case the query is not successful, in any case you would be throwing some error!

> > Will this impact the performance of the application in general? Can it lead to crashing the DB server?

There would be a number of extra & unnecessary queries that you don't need! Crashing of database would depend on a lot of other factors too!

Comment: The thin is, that if this function fails, then I try to connect again.  When the object is created the values have to be supplied to it. What I want to achieve with this is, if the DB connection is closed, reopen it w/o crushing the application.